Finding the least-squares solution for a positive semi-definite matrix
I would like to find the least-squares solution to the problem
$F \vec{p} = \vec{q}$,
where

$F$ is a known real coefficient matrix ($n\times 10$, with $n>10$),
$\vec{p}$ is $10$-element vector of real unknowns, and
$\vec{q}$ is an $n$-element real observable vector.

The least-squares solution to this problem can be found efficiently using a singular value decomposition. However, there is a constraint. The entries of $\vec{p} = [p_0 ... p_9]$ form a real, symmetric, positive semi-definite $4\times 4$-matrix
$P = \begin{bmatrix}
p_0 & p_1 & p_2 & p_3 \\
p_1 & p_4 & p_5 & p_6 \\
p_2 & p_5 & p_7 & p_8 \\
p_3 & p_6 & p_8 & p_9 
\end{bmatrix}  $.
How can I enforce a positive-semidefinite solution during the singular-value least-squares optimization?
My first idea was to solve for the Cholesky-transform $L$ of $P=L L^\top$. But then, I would need to enforce positive diagonal-elements of L...
